# Conference call with both mobile user and Skype user?

Tags: android, skype, conferencing, viber, telegram-messenger

I have PC and Android phone. I have unlimited calls on mobile phones inside country and unlimited wi-fi.

The problem is that my grandparents don`t use internet and my parents live outside of country.

Can I do call via Skype(or any analog) to my parents, call via mobile to my grandparents and make conference?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually make use of [Skype to go](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA1300/what-is-skype-to-go)

And you can check how to make such conference calls [here](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/fa10978/how-can-people-join-my-skype-group-call-from-a-mobile-or-landline)

And you must check if the region you are calling to is in free listings. So that you may call the numbers of that region for free.

Comment: "but you’ll need a Skype Credit or an existing subscription" this means that  unlimited mobile isn`t used.

Comment: Don't know but calls to certain locations are free from Skype. I live in India and I call US numbers from Skype for no cost. Check if the region you are calling to is free for you.